# Troubleshooting a many-to-many relationship in Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access, relational-database

I created a database that holds a STUDENT table, a COURSE table, and an intersection table named STUDENT_COURSE.  However, I have problems with duplicated rows and I don't know how to solve them.

Here are pictures of the tables in design view and many-to-many relationship I have created.

http://imgur.com/P7DI1l&THH7A   (Be sure to click the "Second Image" link to view the relationships picture.)

In an attempt to simplify data entry, I used the form wizard to set up a SCHEDULE form (and subform).

http://imgur.com/isf4Y&ARYu3

As you can see, one enters the student data in the form and the course data associated with that specific student in the subform.  However, when one enters course subform data, it creates a new courseID (autoNumber).  This new courseID results in duplicate courseNames (See "Linear Algebra" entries in above imgur link via "Second Image") so that associated students aren't grouped together when one queries by class.

Is there a flaw in my design?  Am I not using the form correctly to enter data?  Please help me troubleshoot this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your subform should be based on STUDENT_COURSE table and not on COURSE one. You can still add columns from COURSE table to the subform to display course related data.

Here are some links:

1. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/accommodating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-access/5285168
2. http://www.dhdurso.org/articles/ms-access-forms-pg4.html
3. http://en.allexperts.com/q/Using-MS-Access-1440/Help-form.htm

Comment: Is this possible with the Form Wizard or should I do this another way?  I'm having trouble grasping the concept that a form can simply display data on it rather than having to input it.  I'm sorry, I'm just a basic user.  Thank you!

Comment: You can still use Wizard. At least, to start with the form. I posted some links that might be useful (see my updated answer)